# How to modify the program to make it compile?

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;

void push_back(int v, vector<int>& coll) 
{
    coll.push_back(v); 
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> b;
    for_each(a, a + 5, bind2nd(ptr_fun(push_back), b)); 
}
```

the compiler said:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of ‘std::binder2nd<std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, void> >’:
tt5.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:435: error: forming reference to reference type ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&’
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h: In function ‘std::binder2nd<_Operation> std::bind2nd(const _Operation&, const _Tp&) [with _Operation = std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, void>, _Tp = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]’:
tt5.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:455: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::binder2nd<std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, void> >::binder2nd(const std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, void>&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:429: note: candidates are: std::binder2nd<std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, void> >::binder2nd(const std::binder2nd<std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, void> >&)
```

Comment: The fact that you put `using namespace std;` in a line with an `#include` statement caused compilation to fail (but with different error messages of course). After fixing this, it did compile and even work for me (GCC 4.7.0).

Comment: @jogojapan: Doesn't compile for me VS2010: `Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'`

Comment: hi, jogojapan. This mistake appear when i copy my code to the website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is perfectly fine, except that you're using `using namespace std;` which you should be avoiding. In this case, that is *possibly* causing the problem.

So I suggest you to remove `using namespace std;` line, and try using fully-qualified names such as `std::vector` and `std::for_each` etc.

Another fix could be this : just don't use `std::for_each`, as you don't need it.

Write this:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> b(a, a+5);
```

Done!

Now if you want to insert more items later on, then do this:

```
int *c = get_n_items(n); //get n items 
b.insert(b.end(), c, c+n); //insert all items at end
```

Hope that helps.

---

### Your real  scenario:

As you said in the comment:

> On my real work,the source collection element is an object.I just want to pick up a member data from each element and insert them to an vector.

If that is the case, then you should [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Suppose the source is `std::vector<person>` and you want to *pick* `age` member data from each element of this source collection, and insert them into `b` which is `vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<person> persons = get_persons();
std::transform(persons.begin(),        //input begin iterator
               persons.end(),          //input end iterator
               std::back_inserter(b),  //output iterator
               select_age);            //selector
```

where `select_age` is defined as:

```
int select_age(person const & p) { return p.age; }
```

If you can use C++11's lambda, then it is much easier:

```
std::transform(persons.begin(),        //input begin iterator
               persons.end(),          //input end iterator
               std::back_inserter(b),  //output iterator
               [](person const & p) {return p.age;});  //selector
```

Comment: On my real work, It's no choise but use for_each.This is only a little demo program.

Comment: @user1400047: I explained how to use `insert` member function also. Isn't that a better alternative to `for_each`?

Comment: On my real work,the source collection element is an object.I just want to pick up a member data from each element and insert them to an vector.

Comment: @user1400047: Added this text : *"So I suggest you to remove `using namespace std;` line, and try using fully-qualified names such as `std::vector` and `std::for_each` etc."*

Comment: @user1400047: I added a solution for your real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

approach 1

```
void push_back(int v, vector<int>& coll)
{
    coll.push_back(v);
}

for_each(a, a + 5, bind2nd(ptr_fun(push_back), b));
```

approach 2

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

for_each(a, a + 5, boost::bind(&vector<int>::push_back, boost::ref(b), _1));
```

approach 3

```
copy (a, a+5, back_inserter(b));
```